# IPsec no working properly

Tags: vlan, ipsec, packet-tracer

I want to set an IPsec between two routers similar to the one in this lab, however the client on router `EAST` is NATted with the public IP `98.76.65.42`

[image]

on the local side

```
EAST(config)# access-list 110 permit ip 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 123.45.40.0 0.0.0.31
EAST(config)# crypto isakmp policy 10
EAST(config-isakmp)# encryption aes 256
EAST(config-isakmp)# authentication pre-share
EAST(config-isakmp)# group 5
EAST(config-isakmp)# exit
EAST(config)# crypto isakmp key vpnpa55 address 123.45.0.2
EAST(config)# crypto ipsec transform-set VPN-SET esp-aes esp-sha-hmac
EAST(config)# crypto map VPN-MAP 10 ipsec-isakmp
EAST(config-crypto-map)# description VPN connection to R3
EAST(config-crypto-map)# set peer 123.45.0.2
EAST(config-crypto-map)# set transform-set VPN-SET
EAST(config-crypto-map)# match address 110
EAST(config-crypto-map)# exit
EAST(config)# interface s0/0/1
EAST(config-if)# crypto map VPN-MAP
```

on the remote side

```
WEST(config)# access-list 110 permit ip 123.45.40.0 0.0.0.31 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255
WEST(config)# crypto isakmp policy 10
WEST(config-isakmp)# encryption aes 256
WEST(config-isakmp)# authentication pre-share
WEST(config-isakmp)# group 5
WEST(config-isakmp)# exit
WEST(config)# crypto isakmp key vpnpa55 address 98.76.65.42
WEST(config)# crypto ipsec transform-set VPN-SET esp-aes esp-sha-hmac
WEST(config)# crypto map VPN-MAP 10 ipsec-isakmp
WEST(config-crypto-map)# description VPN connection to R3
WEST(config-crypto-map)# set peer 98.76.65.42
WEST(config-crypto-map)# set transform-set VPN-SET
WEST(config-crypto-map)# match address 110
WEST(config-crypto-map)# exit
WEST(config)# interface s0/0/0
WEST(config-if)# crypto map VPN-MAP
```

when I run the command `ping 123.45.40.2` from `Laptop1` the tunnel works and i can confirm that using the command `show crypto ipsec sa` but when i run the command `ping 192.168.1.2` from inside `VLAN 40` I get the error

```
%CRYPTO-4-RECVD_PKT_INV_SPI: decaps rec'd IPSEC packet has invalid spi for destaddr=192.168.1.2, prot=50, spi=0xe00bc6bf(3758868159), srcaddr=123.45.40.2


%CRYPTO-4-IKMP_NO_SA: IKE message from 123.45.40.2 has no SA and is not an  initialization offer
```

on the `EAST` router